# Asp.net deleting asp.net entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having difficulty removing entries from a database in a loop. InvalidOperationException gets thrown. Here is my code.

```
   public static string messageParser(string id)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var ApplicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var UserManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(ApplicationDbContext));
        var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
        string final = "";
        var list =  user.Message.ToList();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            final += item.notification + "\n\n";

            db.Message.Remove(item);

        }   
        db.SaveChanges();
        return final;
    }
```

Comment: Try `var UserManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(db));`

Comment: use a single instanse of `ApplicationDbContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to instatiate a new instance of the Message object.

```
public static string messageParser(User user)
    {
        string final = "";
        if (user != null)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();


            var list = user.Message.ToList();
            foreach (var item in user.Message)
            {
                final += item.notification + "\n\n";

                Message delete = db.Message.Find(item.ID);
                db.Message.Remove(delete);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
        return final;



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just have a single entity that you need to update and shouldn't be doing it in your loop

```
public static string messageParser(string id)
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var UserManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(db));
    var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
    string final = "";
    var list =  user.Message.ToList();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        final += item.notification + "\n\n";
    }   

   db.Message.Remove(user);
   db.SaveChanges();

   return final;
}
```

Comment: I get an invalid operation exception.

Comment: EF works by updating whatever entity you currently have in your context class. If you want to update multiple entities, you need to loop through the entity set, not the list of user messages.